# SQL querying multiple table issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select

I have 3 tables, child, employee, and department with some sample data. I need to fetch:

1. the child name
2. first name and last name of the corresponding employee
3. first name and last name of manager of that employee.

I would like to separate the data in columns based off the criteria above.

child table:

```
+-----------+-------+
| empld_id  | name  |
+-----------+-------+
| 123456789 | Manny |
| 333445555 | Joy   |
| 987654321 | abner |
+-----------+-------+
```

employee table:

```
+-------+-------+-----------+-----+-----------+--------+
| fname | lname |    ssn    | sex | superssn  | deptNo |
+-------+-------+-----------+-----+-----------+--------+
| john  | smith | 123456789 | m   | 333445555 |      5 |
+-------+-------+-----------+-----+-----------+--------+
```

department table:

```
+-----------------+--------+------------+
| department_name | deptNo | managerssn |
+-----------------+--------+------------+
| HQ              |      1 | 8888665555 |
| admin           |      4 | 9876543211 |
+-----------------+--------+------------+
```

I currently have this query:

```
select 
  A.name,
  B.fname, 
  B.lname 
from 
  child A, 
  employee B, 
  department C
where 
  A.empld_id= B.ssn and 
  C.managerssn = B.ssn;
```

Comment: Try to avoid comma seperated joins!

Comment: Have you set up primary and foreign keys on your tables?

Comment: You should most certainly get rid of the [ancient join syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) before you proceed any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there - you have the manager's SSN - now all you need to do is join it back to the employee table to get his details.

To continue your query's style:

```
SELECT c.name, 
       e.fname, e.lname, 
       m.fname AS manager_fname, m.lname AS manager_lname
FROM   child c, employee e, department d, employee m
WHERE  c.empid_id = e.ssn AND d.managerssn = e.ssn AND m.ssn = d.managerssn
```

Note, however, that implicit joins (having multiple tables in the `from` clause) have been deprecated for quite a while, and it's recommended to avoid them and use explicit `join`s instead:

```
SELECT c.name, 
       e.fname, e.lname, 
       m.fname AS manager_fname, m.lname AS manager_lname
FROM   child c
JOIN   employee e ON c.empid_id = e.ssn
JOIN   department d ON d.managerssn = e.ssn
JOIN   employee m ON m.ssn = d.managerssn
```